# Why My tab code Not working perfectly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I trying to apply Tab concept to my web page.e.g for tab names are Monday...Tue.. upto sunday. each tab are contains one image file based on the days (size 460*620).when i run my page it shows all images, what i need is as per the tab image will be display. but here shows all images.

**HTML:**

```
<!--tab code-->
            <div class="tabs" style="margin-top:100px;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#item2">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item3">Item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tabInner">
                    <div id="item1">  <img src="order/Order/image/daily_buffet/40820-sunday.png"/></div>
                    <div id="item2"> <img src="order/Order/image/daily_buffet/50557-tuesday.png"/></div>
                    <div id="item3"> blabla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3 </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <!--end of tab code-->
```

**CSS:**

```
 <!--tab code-->

    .tabs ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .tabs ul li {
        float: left;
        background: #eee;
        border: 1px #aaa solid;
        border-bottom: none;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .tabs ul li.active {
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
    .tabInner {
        clear: both;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #eee;
    }
    .tabInner div {
        height: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
<!--end of tab code-->
```

Comment: your code works on jsfiddle, images are displayed when the corresponding tab is clicked. https://jsfiddle.net/9uyffzf3/ is that how you want the code to work? or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: i change some thing height in `tab inner` now working perfectly thanks for effects

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me. Have you included Jquery into your project? check that once or update the hosted URL.

html

```
<!--tab code-->
            <div class="tabs" style="margin-top:100px;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#item2">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item3">Item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tabInner">
                    <div id="item1">  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/></div>
                    <div id="item2"> <img src="http://sites_jupiterbase2.jumbowp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/thumbnail-placeholder-Copy.jpg"/></div>
                    <div id="item3"> blabla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3bla3 </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <!--end of tab code-->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpx0ymcL/1/

Comment: i change some thing height in tab inner now working perfectly thanks for effects